# Change connection url in sql developer

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to connect to a MySql database using oracle SQL developer but when I try create a new connection it gives to me this error:

> The connection property 'zeroDateTimeBehavior' acceptable values are:
>   'CONVERT_TO_NULL', 'EXCEPTION' or 'ROUND'. The value 'convertToNull'
>   is not acceptable.

Probably I have to change the connection url string since the value "convertToNull" is not recognized, but i don't know how to do it. Can someone help me?

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2410525

Comment: This does not match my request

Comment: Include the details of how you are trying to connect to MySQL from Oracle.

Comment: you can supply your own jdbc url in the Custom connection type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem with the latest version of the JDBC driver for MySQL (8.0.11). When I reverted to the older driver, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

try using any my sql connector versions after 8.0.11, it will work. in my case I have used 8.0.15, it successfully worked.